# ReSharper "Move to resource" does not work

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, resharper

My problem is that the ReSharper command "Move to resource" does not work. The error message states that the command is currently not available.  Tried several times to apply the VS scheme in the ReSharper options dialog without success. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get the error "currently not available" when using "Move to resource" via CTRL-SHIFT-R in the code window you can try to reset both Visual Studio and Resharper key bindings.

1. Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard->Reset
2. Resharper->Options->Environment->Visual Studio Integration->Apply Scheme

Fixed this error for me.

Comment: I don't see how the procedure you're suggesting has anything to do with Move to Resource not being available in a certain code position whereas it's not clear from the question whether other ReSharper commands are available or not.

Comment: Well I had the same error where "Move to Resource" via shortcut ctrl-shift-r was throwing with the message "currently not available". I fixed it by resetting VS + RS bindings. Updated answer with more details on this particular situation.

Comment: Got the same issue and I fixed this by resetting the key bindings.